# How to start my application on phone shutdown event

Tags: android

I am making an android app, in which the app must launch just before the phone is shutting down. Is that possible?

Here i am not talking about encountering phone shutdown event when my app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

And you will listen to the intent like this

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You can look at the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133077/android-action-shutdown-broadcast-not-working) for some description and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) for official documentation.

I don't know the exact application where you want to use it, but you can have a background service running with the receiver for this intent.

Comment: Using the permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />

generates an error "permission only granted to system apps".
is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Never mind i had to correct the settings in eclipse.