# Receive notification of Android's thermal shutdown in my application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, shutdown

I want to receive a notification in my app before Android is going to shutdown due to thermal environment.

Here is a logcat of the shutdown itself:

```
[ 07-26 11:59:16.191   521: 1067 I/system_monitor ]

alarm_callback - Received MAX alarm: batt_therm at Level:1

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

handle_notification - Called

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

handle_notification - Dumping notification

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

name: batt_therm

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

current_level: 0

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

prev_level: 1

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

shutdown_in: 20

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

Adding action: SHUTDOWN

[ 07-26 11:59:16.195   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

handle_notification - Going to callback function

[ 07-26 11:59:16.196   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

[ 07-26 11:59:16.196   968: 6013 I/libsysmon ]

[ 07-26 11:59:16.276   521: 1067 E/system_monitor ]

write_miscta_sysmon_log - read error[10022].

[ 07-26 11:59:16.284   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA Unit 10022: 

[ 07-26 11:59:16.284   186:  186 I/tad      ]

NOT WRITTEN (Identical)

[ 07-26 11:59:16.284   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA: Write of unit 10022 completed - OK

[ 07-26 11:59:16.311   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA Unit 10025: 

[ 07-26 11:59:16.312   186:  186 I/tad      ]

WRITTEN (Size 50)

[ 07-26 11:59:16.409   186:  186 I/tad      ]

Actual erase/write to flash done (count 1, time 1564135156).

[ 07-26 11:59:16.409   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA: Write of unit 10025 completed - OK

[ 07-26 11:59:16.431   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA Unit 10024: 

[ 07-26 11:59:16.431   186:  186 I/tad      ]

WRITTEN (Size 50)

[ 07-26 11:59:16.494   186:  186 I/tad      ]

Actual erase/write to flash done (count 2, time 1564135156).

[ 07-26 11:59:16.494   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA: Write of unit 10024 completed - OK

[ 07-26 11:59:16.501   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA Unit 10023: 

[ 07-26 11:59:16.501   186:  186 I/tad      ]

WRITTEN (Size 50)

[ 07-26 11:59:16.574   186:  186 I/tad      ]

Actual erase/write to flash done (count 3, time 1564135156).

[ 07-26 11:59:16.574   186:  186 I/tad      ]

MiscTA: Write of unit 10023 completed - OK

[ 07-26 11:59:16.576   521: 1067 I/system_monitor ]

Shutting down

[ 07-26 11:59:16.996  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 4.0

[ 07-26 11:59:16.996  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:18.009  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 4.0

[ 07-26 11:59:18.009  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:18.221  2217: 2231 I/art      ]

Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 64885(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 27MB/30MB, paused 9.626ms total 105.405ms

[ 07-26 11:59:18.336   968: 1034 W/PackageManager ]

Invalid verification token 0 received

[ 07-26 11:59:18.993  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 4.0

[ 07-26 11:59:18.993  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:19.984  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 4.0

[ 07-26 11:59:19.984  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:20.983  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 4.0

[ 07-26 11:59:20.983  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:21.666   968: 1572 W/InputMethodManagerService ]

Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@1cafeb50 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@224ee282

[ 07-26 11:59:21.727   968: 1028 I/MediaFocusControl ]

 AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2079c149 req=1flags=0x0

[ 07-26 11:59:22.064   968: 5233 W/ShutdownThread ]

Disabling Bluetooth...

[ 07-26 11:59:22.069   968: 5232 I/ShutdownThread ]

Sending shutdown broadcast...

[ 07-26 11:59:22.078   968: 5232 I/ShutdownThread ]

Shutting down activity manager...

[ 07-26 11:59:22.084   968:  968 W/SyncManager ]

Writing sync state before shutdown...

[ 07-26 11:59:22.097  1930: 1930 I/GPSManager ]

location.getAccuracy() 5.0

[ 07-26 11:59:22.097  1930: 1930 I/AdressUpdate ]

AdressUpdate

[ 07-26 11:59:22.240  4674: 4750 I/BluetoothAdapterState ]

Bluetooth adapter state changed: 12-> 13

[ 07-26 11:59:22.274   968: 5233 W/ShutdownThread ]

Turning off cellular radios...

[
```

How can I receive a broadcast of the shutdown event? Is it possible at all?
There is a line in the log which states the shutdown will be happen in 20 seconds. I would like to get a notification in my application when that event happens - so the app can do the necessary actions before actually shutting down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following in your manifest file:

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

Add Receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make a BroadcastReceiver:

```
private class ShutDownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "System shutting down");
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, BluetoothPanService.class));
        }
    }

}
```

In the main activity's onResume() method instantiate and register the receiver:

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "Measurement Log Activity has Resumed.");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN);
    mReceiver = new ShutDownReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

And finally in the main activity's onPause() unregister the receiver:

```
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "Measurement Log Activity has Paused.");
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102139/how-to-make-action-shutdown-intent-work-when-app-is-closed-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133077/android-action-shutdown-broadcast-not-working). I hope it helps.

Comment: Only one thing I don't get is the line "context.stopService(new Intent(context, BluetoothPanService.class));". Is this related to my question, or just left there unintentionally? Thanks

Comment: Also, I would prefer to get a broadcast about the temperature rising, so I can turn on the fans to make it cooler and prevent the shutdown. (This is in a kiosk - there are fans at the back) Is there something for this? (This is not a new question: "There is a line in the log which states the shutdown will be happen in 20 seconds. I would like to get a notification in my application when that event happens...")

Comment: That is just the user of that code used after getting the signal that the Device is shutting down. He meant to stop a service. You can just remove that line and do whatever you want to do there.

About temperature rising, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797869/how-to-get-cpu-temperature-in-android for CPU temp and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android for Battery Temp. Let me know if your case is solved.

Comment: See this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN
It clearly says that the Broadcast Receiver having Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN will get to notify about the device shutting down. Please clarify what you didn't get.