# Power Off Message Android

Tags: android, smsmanager, power-off

I am using the following intent filters for detecting power off for a device

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
</intent-filter>
```

I intend to send an sms through the receiver of the filters. The filter works well for some devices but in case of certain devices, the receiver does not receive a broadcast and in some other devices sms is not sent. How can this be possibly solved ?

Comment: not sure if this will solve your issue, but diff. approaches are discussed in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133077/android-action-shutdown-broadcast-not-working