# DEVICE_POWER uses permission not working

Tags: android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

I am trying to use this permission but getting an error like this:

> permission is only granted to system apps.

Any solution, or else how to make my app system app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133077/android-action-shutdown-broadcast-not-working

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app